# Use hook in a return function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new in React. If my function name start with uppercase like "ErrorHandler" i can't use hook inside of return function. But if my function name start with lowercase like "errorHandler", everything works fine. Can anyone explain why this is happening?

```
const ErrorHandler = () => {
return props => {
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  return (
     <div>
        <Modal />
     </div>
  )
   }}

export default ErrorHandler
```

Comment: The hook needs to be at the root scope of your function, right after the first `{`.  It shouldn't go into a nested function.  It can likely be used with `errorHandler` because React will think it's a custom hook if you use camel-case.

Comment: You're breaking the rules of hooks by putting the useState in the return function. When you use uppercase, it recognizes that it is a component and then checks that you have not broken the rules of hooks. When you use lowercase, it does not think that you are declaring a component, and lets it go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of the problem here is that React uses the naming convention to determine whether a function is a Component, a custom hook or a regular function or HOC if the hooks are used within the code

If the name starts with an upper case character react assumes that the function is a component and hence validates the rules of hooks against it. Since the hook is not directly within the function it throws you can error

If you use a lower case first character, then react assumes it to a regular function or an HOC and hence by that rule the returned function becomes a component and the rules of hook are not violated.

All validation need to set some ground rules and those the rules set up by react